# jquery append / prepend / wrapInner?

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

Intended outcome:

```
<li><a><span class="icon"></span><span class="text">Link Text</span></a></li>
```

Starting html:

```
<li><a>Link Text</a></li>
```

I've attempted to use `.prepend()` with `.append()` and separately `.wrapInner()` but neither give the desired output.

```
$('li a').wrapInner("<span class='icon'></span><span class='text'></span>");
```

Outputs:

```
<li><a><span class="icon">Link Text</span></a></li>
```

```
$('li a').prepend("<span class='icon'></span><span class='text'>");
$('li a').append("</span>");
```

Outputs:

```
<li><a><span class="icon"></span><span class='text'></span>Link Text</a></li>
```

Is there a way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

check my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/zqUmL/4/) here. I used like below,

```
$('li a').wrapInner("<span class='text'></span>");

$('li a').prepend("<span class='icon'></span>");
```

If you want in 1 line, then use as below

```
$('li a').wrapInner("<span class='text'></span>").prepend("<span class='icon'></span>");
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/zqUmL/9/)** here

Comment: Why on earth do you have your opening and closing tags reversed? `"</span><span class='text'>"`

Comment: This works too, thanks! 1 line vers. is slightly lighter on code than @Matt_H solution.

Comment: +1 This is much better than the destructive `.html()` clobbering.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work:

```
$('li a').html('<span class="icon"></span><span class="text">' + $('li a').html() + '</span>');
```

Comment: Thanks, that works! I thought `.html()` would come into play but not skilled enough in jQuery to resolve it.

Comment: This will not work if there are multiple `li a` elements. And it is a destructive approach that really shouldn't be used.

Comment: @amnotiam what else would u recommend ?

Comment: @TaiKahar: Anything that preserves the existing DOM elements while inserting new content. Otherwise you're generating new HTML markup from the existing DOM, then re-parsing the new markup with its new addition, and finally destroying the old elements, and remaking new ones. This also destroys any event handlers and data associated with the old elements.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work a bit better :)

```
var curText = $('li a').text();

$('li a').html("<span class='icon'></span><span class='text'>"+curText+"</span>");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zqUmL/5/

Answer (score 0):

Is there something wrong with doing this?

```
text = $('li a').html();
$('li a').html("<span class='icon'></span><span class='text'>"+text+"</span>");
```